# Balanced Binary Trees Depth

Tags: binary-tree, max, min, depth, formulas

When given a number of nodes we are able to calculate the min depth of the binary tree by doing log2(n)

Where n is the number of nodes.

If you draw the tree out for the maximum depth for example 12 nodes you work out that the maximum depth can only be 4 if the tree is to remained balanced.

```
                0
               /   \
              0     0
            /  \   / \
           0    0 0   0
          /\     \     \ 
        0   0      0    0
```

Sorry for the bad ascii art. Does anyone know of a forumla that is able to calculate the max depth of a binary tree when given the number of nodes? Or at least point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**By using the root element :**

```
int maxHeight(BinaryTree *p) {
  if (!p) return 0;
  int left_height = maxHeight(p->left);
  int right_height = maxHeight(p->right);
  return (left_height > right_height) ? left_height + 1 : right_height + 1;
}
```

---

**By using the number of nodes and some math logic** (which I definitely cannot express properly (I'm by no means a math guru); but here it is) :

**Observation :**

- 2-3 nodes => maxDepth = 1     (2 = 2^1,  3 = 2^1,..  < 2^2 )
- 4-7 nodes => maxDepth = 2     (4 = 2^2,  5 = 2^2,.., 6 = 2^2,.., 7 = 2^2,...  < 2^3)
- 8-15 nodes => maxDepth = 3
- ...

**Analysis :**

> - m => max Depth (actual the INT part of the depth, discard any decimal places)
> - n => number of nodes
> - ln => natural logarithm (=log[e])

- 2^m = n
- ln(2^m) = ln(n)
- m*ln(2) = ln(n)
- m = ln(n)/ln(2)

**Conclusion :**

Now, if m = 2,... , then the maximum depth is 2. Just get the int part of it. ;-)

---

***NOTE:** I'm definitely re-inventing the wheel here; but that's probably part of the fun of dealing with something you know nothing about; and doing it, solely following your instinct and observations... :-)*

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer looks like this:

```
int getMaxDepth(Node node)
{
    if(node == null) {
        return 0;
    }

    int leftDepth = 1 + getMaxDepth(node.left);
    int rightDepth = 1 + getMaxDepth(node.right);

    return left > right ? left : right;
}
```

The concept [explained](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4bncAOf4XkM)

Answer (score 1):

Let no of nodes given(n)=15
Formula is- log2n (log n base 2)
now take a max value which must be less than 15 and must be a power result of 2.
As here 15 is given the no will be 8.
Now, n=8
log2(8)= 3 ,which is our required answer